# Configurar un botón para copiar contenido de un GridView C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quisiera saber cómo puedo configurar un botón para que copie los datos de un GridView que contiene 3 tablas Codigo, Cantidad y PrecioU pero solamente copiar el contenido de ellas, sin el titulo.

Comment: Dirás que tiene 3 columnas. hacia donde quieres copiarlo ? a otra GridView ?

Comment: Al portapapeles, porque el usuario pegará esa información en otro programa nada que ver con el que estoy haciendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré información en una página de *asp.net* dice que solo funciona en Internet Explorer, podrías intentar y ver si es compatible con otros navegadores. Espero que te sirva. 

***Función de javascript:***

```
//Referencia a jQuery en caso de necesitarla
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CopyGridView()
{
    var div = document.getElementById('divGridView');
    // Si quieres eliminar las filas del titulo utiliza este metodo con jquery
    //var div = $('#divGridView').clone();
    //$(div).find('thead,tr>th').remove();
    div.contentEditable = 'true';
    var controlRange;
    if (document.body.createControlRange) {
    controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
    controlRange.addElement(div);
    controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
    }
    div.contentEditable = 'false';
}
</script>
```

Hay que poner un **DIV** antes del **GridView** con el ID que desees y mandar llamar esta función en un botón, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="divGridView">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" onclick="CopyGridView()" style="position: static" type="button" value="button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: No me reconoce el método "CopyGridView()" :( `CS1061: 'liquidacion_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'CopyGridView' and no extension method 'CopyGridView' accepting a first argument of type 'liquidacion_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Recuerda que esta es una funcion de javascript, si utilizas un botón de asp.net tendrías que utililzar el parametro onclientclick="CopyGridView();" y como es un método no olvides poner los paréntesis al final ()

Comment: Ok, si funciona, pero crees poder decirme como hago para que los títulos no se copeen tambièn?

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, intenta con eso ocupa de jquery

Comment: Me aparece `Error: '$' no está definido` cuando le doy clic al botón

Comment: Agrega la referencia de jquery en tu header <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Pero sigue el error...

Comment: Acabo de actualizar agregando la referencia intenta de esta manera

Comment: Y ahora es `Error: Interfaz no compatible` Ahhhh!!!!